# Why is ansible-core 2.12 not running Ansible core 2.12?

Tags: ansible

I've been updating an Ansible project, and as part of that I tried to update an assertion about the Ansible version:

```yaml
- name: Check Ansible version
  assert:
    that:
      - ansible_version.major == 2 and ansible_version.minor >= 5
```

I figured the version corresponded to the version of the ansible-core package installed, but that doesn't seem to be the case: it's installing ansible-core 2.12.3 and ansible 5.5.0, but changing the assertion to `ansible_version.major == 2 and ansible_version.minor >= 12` results in a failure. If `ansible_version` corresponds to *neither* version, what does it correspond to?

Answer (score -1):

The project is still using Python 3.6 (don't worry, upgrading it is on the way), which is no longer supported:

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) [GCC 8.4.0]. This feature will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.12.

I *was* wondering why that was an error rather than a warning, considering I'm actually running Ansible (core) 2.12. But the very next line indicates that core 2.12 is capable of running with an older core:

> ansible-playbook [core 2.11.9]

Comment: This indicates that you are not running the version of Ansible that you think you are. ansible-core 2.12 will never report that it is 2.11.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I'm installing 2.12, that's what APT is reporting.

Comment: But clearly the version that apt is installing is not the one that you are running, so you should investigate why that is the case. `which ansible-playbook` is a good first step.